# ps aux not wrapping lines

Tags: linux, ps

When I do 'ps aux' a lot of the lines are longer than the width of my terminal, and not wrapping to the next line.  At first I thought it was my stty settings, but I noticed that other commands like netstat do wrap lines in my terminal.  I would prefer not to be forced to use less or some other pager.

Does anybody know why the lines are not wrapping?  and how to fix?

Answer (score 54):

There is also another simple solution:

```sh
echo "$(ps aux)"
```

The paranthesis will execute the command in a subshell which i guess has no **width** specification and therefore does not cut the lines, at least on every shell i tried this is the case.

Printing it with Quotes make the print command to keep the Newlines:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc11

Comment: While it fixes the wrapping issue, it introduces the issue where the columns no longer line up at all, giving you one very long line that's unreadable.  It seems to remove or change some of the whitespace in the ps output.

Comment: Are you sure you executed the command exactly how i wrote it? If you remove the quotes it will printed as one block / one line. If you add the quote the line breaks will be printed. Read: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc11

Comment: This worked in an Alpine Linux container.

Answer (score 20):

from `man(1) ps` OUTPUT MODIFIERS

```
[UN*X]  -w   Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.
[BSD]   w    Wide output.  Use this option twice for unlimited width.
```

I tend to the UN*X variant `ps -ef` and add, as a mnemonic, **word wrap** to make:
    `~ $ ps -efww`
    but 
    `~ $ ps auxww`
is equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

`ps` is a rather old command. It reads the width of the terminal and sets up the format accordingly. You could override this with the `--cols` option.

```
 $ ps aux --cols 100
 ...
 user    29246  8.0 19.7 1748240 763200 ?      Sl   Dec05 364:04 /usr/lib/firefo
 x/firefox
 user    31490  0.0  1.0 235660 39256 ?        Sl   Dec05   0:06 /usr/bin/evince 
 /tmp/space_draft_wo
 ...
```

And then with longer lines

```
 $ ps aux --cols 120
 ...
 user    29246  8.0 19.7 1748240 763200 ?      Sl   Dec05 364:04 /usr/lib/firefo
 x/firefox
 user    31490  0.0  1.0 235660 39256 ?        Sl   Dec05   0:06 /usr/bin/evince 
 /tmp/space_draft_work_programme.pdf
 ...
```

Comment: I had to use 'ps aux --cols 10000'.  When I used 100, the lines were still getting chopped off when it reached the width of my terminal.  For some reason I don't have to specify that at work, perhaps it is configured in /etc/init.d or something like that.

Comment: Correction: lines were getting chopped off when it reached 100 characters, and not wrapping to the next line.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. Any suggestions on how to automate this with `ansi-term`? Should I write an alias in `.bashrc` or `init.el / .emacs`?

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned piping it to less, but I still think piping to `more` or `less` is still the simplest solution, wherever you can afford it. (ie, in an interactive session)